# DataSource maxActive does not change in tomcat mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jmx

I'm using win7-eclipse-tomcat7-mysql5.

First, set datasource resource in TOMCAT_DIRECTORY/conf/context.xml

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive=100 maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="dev_id" password="dev_password"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db_name" />
</Context>
```

And in ECLIPSE/MY_PROJECT/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

After setting up, I run my eclipse tomcat 7.0 server.

Then find maxActive in jconsole. 
[image]

Why maxActive can not change?? Help me, please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my answer :)

In eclipse, WTP has own settings.

You see the tomcat server setting files in your /server folder.

If you run eclipse WTP, TOMCAT_DIRECTORY/conf/context.xml doesn't effect your server. It only depends on resource files in eclipse/server/